# curl no url specified // Text to Speech IBM Bluemix

Tags: curl, command-line, ibm-cloud

I start using Text to Speech with curl and i'm in trouble. I copy the code from the exemple in the command line with my credentials but there is an error i can't solve : curl : no URL specified!

Here is the code i try :

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password} \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Accept: audio/wav" \
--data "{\"text\":\"hello world\"}" \
--output hello_world.wav \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize"
```

Here the code in the command line (win10) :

[Curl in command line no url specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV66a.png)

Can i have any help please ? :)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows prompt it is daunting due to **quote within quote**. I tried this out and work:

1. The original post in IBM web site/cloud has TWO versions,

--data '{"text": "hello world"}', another one is
--data "{\"text\":\"hello world\"}'

(ie. if you use only double quote within double quote, you must use \, and also no space after :)

2. if you use the second way, you can't have space after colon:
   So better always delete the space for safe.
3. Both of the following works:

-X POST -u "apikey:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: audio/wav" --data '{"text":"hello world"}' --output hello_world.wav  "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/api/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize"

C:\Users\rpo\IBM-Watson>curl -X POST -u "apikey:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: audio/wav" --data "{\"text\":\"hello world\"}" --output "hello_world.wav"  https://stream.watsonplatform.net/api/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize

4. It seems no need to quote the http string...

Answer (score 0):

You left no space in between the (unnecessarily quoted) URL and the value of the `--output` switch.

Comment: It still don't work. Always the same error no URL specified.

Comment: You're escaping whitespace that you want to be normal and treated as argument separators, and mismatching quotes in the image. Single quoting the entire data value and writing it normally, `--data '{"text":"hello world"}'`, should be enough.